# How to Run MySQL without installation and access with IP address (like http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpdesktop

i have to download MySQL zip from this site (https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and run it with cmd but i want to run it with php code and access database with IP address like Xampp or wamp server (http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin).
please help me about this problem.

thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of your problem. It is not clear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have done is installed the core of the mysqli. so It does not come with a GUI.
So you will have to manually download the GUI and install it.. its called mysqli workbench

here in this [link](http://%20https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/.) download it.
you can't use mysqli like phpmyadmin because its a desktop version. If you really want to use the browser version you will have to install wampserver [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/)